# iPad iPhone: Calling Webview from anther View Controller class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview, webview

I'm new to this as I come from C++ and Perl background. Trying to learn from books but they are missing some core concepts of Objective-C. I need some help on this code to pull a webpage:

**RootViewController.m**

```
    - (void)fetchWebsite:(NSString*)website{
    NSLog(@"address: %@", website);

    NSString *urlAddress = website;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webImageDisplay loadRequest:requestObj];
    [webImageDisplay release];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self fetchWebsite:@"website here"];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

This code works just fine but what I'm having trouble is calling this method from another class, like the code below:

I'm correctly calling the detail view controller from a 2nd view controller like this:

**SubViewController.m**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0: { 
            AnotherViewController *cViewController = [[AnotherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnotherViewController" bundle:nil];
            cController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 350);
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:cViewController animated:YES];
            [cViewController release];
            break;
        }
        case 1: {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have a 3rd view controller that has the links to a new webpage which I want displayed on the webview. When I call the method here to access the function in RootViewController, it doesn't seem to respond.

**AnotherViewController.m**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *itemRequested = [conusItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"logging: %@", itemRequested);

    RootViewController *parent = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
    [parent fetchWebsite:@"another website here"];

    [itemRequested release];

}
```

I click on the button on the table view and I see the code is being called in the RootViewController with the NSLog but it doesn't seem to display the new page. No errors or warnings, Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I may, you're life will be easier and your application will be more flexible if you spin your web view out as it's own view controller.

The real problem is you aren't navigating to your web view controller (and you might not be initializing it correctly.)

Chances are the code will look more like this:

```
MyWebViewController *webVC = [[MyWebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyWebViewContorller" bundle:nil];
webVC.address = @"whatever";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:webVC animated:YES];
[webVC release];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things going on here worth noting.

- In didSelectRowAtIndexPath, you're creating a view controller but you don't present it so there's no visible side effect.   The typical thing done to present a "detail" view controller from a table view is this:

```
MenuItemOrderVC *vc = [[MenuItemOrderVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuItemOrderVC" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
[vc release];
```

This creates a new instance of the view controller class, and presents it by pushing on to the stack of the navigation controller.  That's the usual way to show a detail view.

If what you're trying to do is really present the data on a different view controller that already exists (and is hidden at the moment?), then you should not be allocating a new RootViewController (given the name, you probably shouldn't create more than one, usually the "root" view controller is the base of your VC stack and only one exists throughout the application, but that's not a hard and fast rule).  Instead, you will need a way to get the object pointer to your already existing RootViewController.

You'll need to either pass down the RootViewController object from ViewController to ViewController, or put it in some globally accessible place, like in your app delegate subclass, and do something like this:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDel = (MyAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
RootViewController *rvc = appDel.rootViewController;
```

If you can comment on which of these two options you were thinking of, I can give a more directed answer.

Comment: Sorry for not elaborating. I'm trying to do this http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/using-popoverview-ipad-app-development but 3rd view controller in it doesn't seem I can correctly call webview from the rootController to pull up a new page.